# R6RS vs. R5RS scheme

Tags: scheme, r6rs, r5rs

I'm relatively new to scheme and am having a hard time finding a concrete document online overviewing the major changes that happened with R6RS. Anyone care to elaborate?

Comment: R5RS and R6RS are worlds apart, and it's probably worth treating them as totally separate languages.

Answer (score 14):

http://community.schemewiki.org/?R6RS has compiled a list of high level changes with some commentary, including:

- case sensitive syntax
- square brackets are now equivalent to parentheses (e.g., `(let ([foo 3]) ...)` - this was supported in some scheme implementations but is now part of the standard
- retaining the ability to return multiple `values`
- more escape characters in strings, e.g., `"\n"`
- hashtables as a library
- multiline and expression comments

http://www.r6rs.org/versions/CHANGES

http://www.r6rs.org/formal-comments/

http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1342

If you're relatively new to scheme and have the fortitude you will get more mileage [reading the spec](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs.html) instead of skimming a changelog though...

Comment: I know this list just quotes the site, but I don't think evaluation order has ever been a subject of any Scheme report and has always been unspecified.